# How to fadeOut and fadeIn instead of only fadeIn

Tags: jquery

The first image goes away directly and the seconde fades in,
I want the first image to fade out (animated).

Please notice the transition css, please tell me why the image goes away directly eventhough any opacity change should be transitioned.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  'use strict';

  if (jQuery('#home-slider .home-slide').length > 0) {
    var slide = function () {
      jQuery('#home-slider .home-slide').removeClass('current');
      jQuery('#home-slider .home-slide:first').appendTo( jQuery('#home-slider') );
      jQuery('#home-slider .home-slide:first').addClass('current');
    }
    slide();
    setInterval(function () {
      slide();
    }, 4000);
  }
  
});
```

```css
#home-slider {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#home-slider .home-slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  
  transition: opacity 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#home-slider .home-slide:first-of-type {
  transition: opacity 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-slider">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="home-slide" />
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ff0000/000000" class="home-slide" />
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0000ff/000000" class="home-slide" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/t3m5jngt/). I think this is what you need. I used `jquery` in here. Hope this will help you.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  function infinite() {
      $(".gallery img").each(function(i) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).delay(1500*i).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(500);
      }).promise().done(infinite);
  }
  infinite();
});
```

```css
.gallery{ position: relative; width: 180px; }
.gallery img{ width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
 <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/7d09jn2np/image.png" alt="">
 <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/ma8qknfw5/image.png" alt="">
 <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/dt989qb79/image.png" alt="">
</div>
```